# How to use Pionner 3AT + Sensor Kinect to capture point clouds

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I'm using Pionner 3AT + Sensor Kinect to capture point clouds. I'm use the p2os (teleop_keyboard) to controll robotic and rgbdslam_freiburg to capture the point clouds, I don't have problems for to use these processes separately, the problem is when I use the two together. What must I do to rgbdslam package receive the commands to capture the point cloud (ex: "enter" key)? I have the same doubt with joystick.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/61456/how-to-use-pionner-3at-+-sensor-kinect-to-capture-point-clouds/) by [lf.wil](https://answers.ros.org/users/4749/lf.wil/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-04-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I assume your problem is controlling the Pioneer remotely and using rgbdslam at the same time. You could try using rgbdslam in [headless mode](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rgbdslam#Usage_via_ROS_service_calls_.28possibly_headless.29) and use the `frame` service call. As for controlling the Pioneer with a joystick remotely, you can try a [multiple machine](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/MultipleMachines) setup with a desktop PC running the joystick node.

---

Originally posted by [georgebrindeiro](https://answers.ros.org/users/2573/georgebrindeiro/) with karma: 1264 on 2013-04-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lf.wil](https://answers.ros.org/users/4749/lf.wil/) on 2013-07-10**:
Thanks! I used rgdslam in headless ode and got sucess.